# Component event not firing or not being catched

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, event

I spent the whole day trying to figure out why this event is not getting fired, i tried both component and application events but noting worked although the code is pretty simple.

here is my code :

**Event: EVT01_deleteItems**

```
    <aura:event type="COMPONENT" >
    <aura:attribute name="item" type="To_do_Items__c"/>
 </aura:event>
```

**Child component: CMP03_Item**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" controller="TestContactLevels">

<aura:attribute name="Item" type="To_do_Items__c" />
<aura:registerEvent name="deleteItem" type="c:EVT01_deleteItems" />

<article class="slds-card">
   <lightning:icon title="Supprimer la tache" iconName="utility:delete" size="xx-small" class="icon"
                        onclick="{!c.deleteItem}" />
</article>
```

**Child component controller :**

```
deleteItem : function(cmp, event, helper) {
    var itemToBeDeleted = cmp.get("v.Item");
    var deleteEvent = cmp.getEvent("deleteItem");
    deleteEvent.setParams({"item": itemToBeDeleted });
    deleteEvent.fire();

}
```

**Parent component: CMP02_toDoListItems**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="itemsToDisplay" type="To_do_Items__c[]" />
<aura:handler name="deleteItem" type="c:EVT01_deleteItems" action="{!c.mDeleteItem}"  /> 
<aura:iteration items="{!v.itemsToDisplay}" var="item">
   <c:CMP03_Item Item="{!item}"/>
</aura:iteration>
```

**Parent component controller:**

```
    mDeleteItem: function(cmp,event,helper){
   // nothing here, just a console log 
    console.log("does it work ? ");
}
```

am i missing something here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In handler you have

```
<aura:handler name="deleteItem" type="c:EVT01_deleteItems" action="{!c.mDeleteItem}"  />
```

But type is incorrect, you must use: event

```
<aura:handler name="deleteItem" event="c:EVT01_deleteItems" action="{!c.mDeleteItem}"  />
```

Here you can see this in the [official doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_component_example.htm).